# Regex with SQL Server 2008 CLR performance issues

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

I am trying to understand why is it taking so long to execute a simple query.
In my local machine it takes 10 seconds but in production it takes 1 min.
(I imported the database from production into my local database)

```
select * 
from JobHistory
where dbo.LikeInList(InstanceID, 'E218553D-AAD1-47A8-931C-87B52E98A494') = 1
```

The table `DataHistory` is not indexed and it has 217,302 rows

```
public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static bool LikeInList([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]SqlString value, [SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]SqlString list)
    {
        foreach (string val in list.Value.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None))
        {
            Regex re = new Regex("^.*" + val.Trim() + ".*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (re.IsMatch(value.Value))
            {
                return(true);
            }
        }

        return (false);
    }
};
```

And the issue is that if a table has 217k rows then I will be calling that function 217,000 times! not sure how I can rewrite this thing.

Thank you

Comment: Wonder if there are any memory pressure issues on the server when this runs? What is the hw config for the server and SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code:

1. Missing `(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)` in `[SqlFunction]` attribute. Doing this (mainly just the `IsDeterministic = true` part) will allow the SQLCLR UDF to participate in parallel execution plans. Without setting `IsDeterministic = true`, this function will prevent parallel plans, just like T-SQL UDFs do.
2. Return type is `bool` instead of `SqlBoolean`
3. RegEx call is inefficient: using an instance method once is expensive. Switch to using the static `Regex.IsMatch` instead
4. RegEx pattern is *very* inefficient: wrapping the search string in "^.*" and ".*$" will require the RegEx engine to parse *and* retain in memory as the "match", the entire contents of the `value` input parameter, for every single iteration of the `foreach`. Yet the behavior of Regular Expressions is such that simply using `val.Trim()` as the entire pattern would yield the exact same result.
5. (optional) If *neither* input parameter will ever be over 4000 characters, then specify a `MaxSize` of `4000` instead of `-1` since `NVARCHAR(4000)` is much faster than `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for passing data into, and out of, SQLCLR objects.

Comment: I did the changes in the DLL and noticed a very small improvement. The problem is in our SQL query which is calling the SQL CLR assembly. I want to say thank you for taking the time to try to help me, thank you!

Comment: @Max You're welcome. Please see my update for item #4. I didn't format it correctly at first and was missing the `*` in both string items mentioned. Maybe you understood from what was written, but if taken literally, it was incomplete.

Comment: @Max so was it really the query? Does that mean that changing the query got this to work much faster?